# GitHub - How to check which user was used for cloning repo?

Tags: linux, github, terminal

I cloned specific GitHub repo several days ago. Repo does not seem to exist anymore when I go to `https://github.com/repo...` - it does not exist anymore.

How to check which user was used for cloning repo? 
I went into terminal into a folder where repo was cloned into and can check which repo is used: `git remote -v`

But when try this:

```
git config user.name 
git config --global user.name
```

nothing shows.

How to see which user was used to clone/commit this repo?

Answer (score -3):

`git remote -v` should give you list of remotes and their URLs, one of them (perhaps the only one) should be "origin" which should be the URL you used to clone from.

Comment: The github repo URLs follow the form `htts://github.com/<username>/<reponame>`.

Comment: It is `htts://github.com/<Organization>/<reponame>` (e.g. `https://github.com/facebook/react.git`)